# SUM of time field in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

following is my SOQL
I want total time spent on the same date. But sum is not supported for time field. is there any other option to do that.

```
Select id,Case__c,SUM(Time__c),Date__c from Case_session__c Group By Date__C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Time` field type does not represent a duration. It represents a single point in time, without associated `Date` information - for example, `19:00:00.000Z`. Because the displayed value of a `Time` field is adjusted for the time zone of the running user, it should not be (mis-)used to treat the hours and minutes as a duration. This will result in unexpected results when users in different time zones view the data.

As a consequence of the above, summing `Time` values is not meaningful, any more than summing `DateTime` values would be.

Comment: +1 for different time zones view.

Answer (score 0):

Time field doesn't support any [aggregate function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions_field_types.htm) but there is a workaround.
You can create a formula field (Number type) where time will always be in hours. So if it's **01:30** in the time field then your formula will have **1.5** after converting it to hours from milliseconds.

Now, you can use the aggregate function in the number type formula field.